# modrewrite not picking up images from css

Tags: css, mod-rewrite

I have the following ModRewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^img/(.*) /wp/wp-content/themes/vizu/img/$1 [QSA,L]
```

It works when the images are referenced from php like `http://123.com/wp/img/test.jpg`
showing the image located at `http://123.com/wp/wp-content/themes/vizu/img/test.jpg`

I have a CSS file `/wp/wp-content/themes/vizu/css/style.css`
where I set some background images like so

```
background-image:url(../img/left_menu_bg2-2.png);
```

This works on my develeopment server on windows, but not on the production LAMP server, please tell me how can I reference images in CSS so they are picked up by the ModRewrite rule?

Comment: use `url(/img/left_menu_bg2-2.png)` instead. But the old urls should still work, so I'm not sure the RewriteRule is the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing the URL between single quotes will fix it.

```
background-image:url('../img/left_menu_bg2-2.png');
```